# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid on wrong column - Postgresql 14.2

Tags: postgresql, function, postgraphile, postgresql-14

I am in progress of writing a function that takes 2 objects. My goal is to have the restaurant be optionally inserted if it does not exist followed by inserting the food item into its respective tables. I need to write a function because I am using postgraphile to make the request to insert the data.

Here is my SQL schema definition:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;

-- Restaurant table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurants
(   id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name citext NOT NULL,
    address citext NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name, address)
);

-- Restaurant items table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurant_items
(   id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name citext NOT NULL,
    restaurant_id uuid NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name, restaurant_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants (id)
);

-- Custom types that don't include certain fields
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_restaurant_item AS
    SELECT id, name 
    FROM restaurant_items 
    WHERE false;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW restaurant_with_new_item AS
    SELECT r.name AS rest_name, r.address, ri.* 
    FROM restaurants r, restaurant_items ri 
    WHERE false;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_restaurant_item_with_restaurant(
    p_restaurant restaurants,
    p_restaurant_item new_restaurant_item
) RETURNS restaurant_with_new_item AS 
$$
    DECLARE inserted_restaurant restaurants;
    DECLARE inserted_restaurant_item restaurant_items;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO restaurants(id, name, address)
    VALUES (p_restaurant.id, p_restaurant.name, p_restaurant.address)
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT restaurants_name_address_key
        DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name
    RETURNING name AS rest_name, address INTO inserted_restaurant;
    
    INSERT INTO restaurant_items(id, name, restaurant_id)
    VALUES (p_restaurant_item.id, p_restaurant_item.name, p_restaurant.id)
    RETURNING *, inserted_restaurant INTO inserted_restaurant_item;

    RETURN inserted_restaurant_item;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I would rather not have to keep redundantly specifying columns as much as possible, which is why I opted for a custom view that acts as a type for the parameters for the function. When I go to execute the function through both postgraphile and through normal SQL, it states the following with the given query:

```
SELECT * FROM add_restaurant_item_with_restaurant(
    ROW('a81bc81b-dead-4e5d-abff-90865d1e13b1', 'abc', 'def'),
    ROW('a81bc81b-dead-4e5d-abff-90865d1e13b2', 'abcd')
);

--Result:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: "abc"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function add_restaurant_item_with_restaurant(restaurants,new_restaurant_item) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 22P02
```

Oddly if the first field (the actual `uuid`) is not a valid uuid it complains about that field. And I only have one uuid field on the table. I am kinda stumped. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: The table `restaurant_items` has two `uuid` fields and you are inserting into both of them with: `INSERT INTO restaurant_items(id, name, restaurant_id)`.  Though I am not sure how `abc` is getting to either one. You might want to `RAISE NOTICE` on the data being used in the function to see if it what you think it is?

Comment: @Adrian Looks like I solved it, but I totally didn't know there was a way to do logging like that! I was so confused in how I could log what was going on. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved it! Patrick's answer helped me slightly however there was a deeper problem with the query itself it seems. After trying a bunch of different things, I ended up using the types like Patrick suggested and replacing the inserted_restaurant here

```
INSERT INTO restaurant_items(id, name, restaurant_id)
    VALUES (p_restaurant_item.id, p_restaurant_item.name, p_restaurant.id)
    RETURNING *, inserted_restaurant INTO inserted_restaurant_item;
```

with `inserted_restaurant.*` while also manually specifying the other fields to match the new type I added. This change seems fix it completely as with all the other changes I removed it temporarily to see what would happen and it is giving me a similar problem, but with the entire set/row.

I also noticed that the type of the variable `inserted_restaurant_item` was wrong and didn't encapsulate the type of restaurant and restaurant item with how I am returning it which might have been a factor.

Together the types and function definition look like this:

```
CREATE TYPE new_restaurant_item AS (id uuid, name citext);
CREATE TYPE new_item_with_restaurant AS (
    id uuid,
    name citext,
    rest_id uuid,
    rest_name citext,
    address citext
);

-- Add restaurant if it doesn't exist and the food associated with it
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_restaurant_item_with_restaurant(
  p_restaurant restaurants,
  p_restaurant_item new_restaurant_item
)
RETURNS new_item_with_restaurant AS $$
  DECLARE inserted_restaurant restaurants;
  DECLARE inserted_restaurant_item new_item_with_restaurant;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO restaurants(id, name, address)
    VALUES (p_restaurant.id, p_restaurant.name, p_restaurant.address)
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT restaurants_name_address_key DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name
      RETURNING id AS rest_id, name AS rest_name, address INTO inserted_restaurant;
    
  INSERT INTO restaurant_items(id, name, restaurant_id)
    VALUES (p_restaurant_item.id, p_restaurant_item.name, p_restaurant.id)
    RETURNING id, name, inserted_restaurant.* INTO inserted_restaurant_item;

  RETURN inserted_restaurant_item;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thank you, Patrick, for leading me down the right direction!